# Laravel 8/Passport/GuzzleHttp APO returns 200 OK but no body response

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

i'm trying to setup vue.js login page (front-end) with Laravel 8 (back-end) using Passport and GuzzleHttp.

oAuth/Token: works correctly (tested with Insomnia)
userData: works correctly (tested with Insomnia)

Testing Domain is setup by local virutal host (XAMPP).

My controller looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function login (Request $request)
    {
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
        try {
            $response = $http->post('http://testapp.test/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => 2,
                    'client_secret' => 'TOKEN',
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                ]
            ]);
            return $response->getBody();
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
                return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
            } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
                return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
            }
            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
        }


    }

}
```

My api routes looks like:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login');
```

When I make Post request via Insomnia with username/password to testapp.test/api/login it returns 200 OK but showing only message "No body returned for response". It should show the Bearer token.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to get `->getContents()` to get Contents.

```
$response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

It will return you json.

Comment: Hi Dilip, thanks. But this is not the solution - i have added this (also tried it before) - same result. 200OK but "No body returned for response"